# Displaying common key words in a user inputed variable and dict

Tags: python, dictionary, input, return

How would you go about referencing a dictionary with a user input and printing out the corresponding value associated with said words in the dictionary? For example say I input "value" and in the dictionary "value" is associated with the the data 1; how would I be able to print that or carry it over to be used again?

```
class Rating(object):

    def enter(self):
        exit(1)

class userInput():

    def inputReview(self):
        review = ""
        print "Welcome to our review system! Please input review text below."
        review = raw_input("> ")
        print ""

        goodWords = {
        'value': 1,
        'Solid': 2,
        'faster': 3,
        'great': 4,
        'beast': 5
        }

        badWords = {
        'slow': 1,
        'aftermarket': 2,
        'weak': 3,
        'dropping': 4.,
        'freezes': 5,
        }

        print goodWords.values()
        print ""

        if review in goodWords:
            print goodWords[review]
        else:
            exit(1)




class review():
    pass

a = userInput()
a.inputReview()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you rephrase what you want to achieve?

Comment: that is what you are doing. You are printing the value of whatever key you input. Also you don't need to declare review as an empty string just `review = raw_inpt()` is fine

Comment: @alvas When a word inputed in variable and is matched in dictionary I want the value associated to be printed. So when I place value in review I want the corresponding date, in this case 1, to be printed out.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham trouble is it wont. I'm using the terminal btw

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance and call the method on the instance:

```
class userInput():

    def inputReview(self):
        print "Welcome to our review system! Please input review text below."
        review = raw_input("> ")
        print ""

        goodWords = {
        'value': 1,
        'Solid': 2,
        'faster': 3,
        'great': 4,
        'beast': 5
        }

        badWords = {
        'slow': 1,
        'aftermarket': 2,
        'weak': 3,
        'dropping': 4.,
        'freezes': 5,
        }

        print goodWords.values()
        print ""

        if review in goodWords:
            print goodWords[review]
        else:
            exit(1)
foo = userInput() # create instance of the class

foo.inputReview() # call method on the instance
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: foo = userInput()

In [6]: foo.inputReview()
Welcome to our review system! Please input review text below.
> value

[2, 5, 4, 3, 1]

1
```

[python classes tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Unless you plan on adding more methods I would just make it a function.

Comment: Alright I see what you did there. Still new to the language and programing in general. Could you explain the answer to me?

Comment: @JCD, really the only thing to explain is you must create an instance and then you access the methods of the class with that instance. Like my final comment in the answer a class is overkill if you only have a single method, you should simply make it a function and forget the class

Comment: @JCD, I added a link that gives you very basic easy to follow examples of how to use classes

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer. I originally planned on having multiple functions within the class but from what I gathered transferring variable data between functions is not possible which was led me to having this one function. Am I wrong about transferring variable data between functions in the same class?

Comment: that is completely possible,  you should create attributes/properties in something called an `__init__ ` method then you can use them in any method you like

Comment: There is an example in the link